# Solving inequality by induction associated with a recurrence

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

Consider the sequence an defined by $a_1=1$, $a_2=3$ and

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2} \text{ for } n>2.$$

Prove that $$a_n<
\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^n\text{ for every positive integer }n.$$

My attempt: By induction, we assume that $a_k<(\frac{7}{4})^k$

Now, we need to prove to $n=k+1$. I did: $a_k<(\frac{7}{4})^k$, and $\frac{7}{4}.a_k<(\frac{7}{4})^{k+1}$.

I assumed that $a_{k+1}\le a_k\cdot\frac{7}{4}$

I replaced the minor cases and it always worked, but I am not able to prove this inequality by induction

Comment: You haven't used $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. You gotta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the recurrence depends on $2$ previous steps, you need to assume $2$ steps in the inductive hypothesis.

Inductive hypothesis: $a_k \le (7/4)^k$ and $a_{k+1} \le (7/4)^{k+1}.$

Inductive step: you need to prove that $a_{k+2}\le(7/4)^{k+2}$. Can you do this step using the recurrence $a_{k+2}=a_{k+1}+a_{k}$?

> $$a_{k+2}=a_{k+1}+a_{k}\le(7/4)^{k+1}+(7/4)^k=(7/4)^k(1+7/4)=(7/4)^k(44/16)<(7/4)^k(49/16)=(7/4)^{k+2}$$

Note: you’ll also need to prove $2$ base cases.

> $a_1 = 1 < 7/4, \quad a_2 = 3 = 48/16 < 49/16$

If you’re interested, these are almost the [Lucas numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number) and the proof works essentially because $7/4 > \phi$ the golden ratio.